# What is the correct/ best way to handle custom ServiceStack exceptions on the client side?

Tags: c#, exception, servicestack

I am trying to simplify error handling in my client application which consumes a ServiceStack REST service using the `JsonServiceClient`.

My custom exceptions that I throw on the server are serialised in the `ResponseStatus` object, and I can see a `WebServiceException` is thrown.

But at the moment I am having to check for my exception types, by matching the `WebServiceException` `ErrorCode` to the type name of my exception class. (Which is exposed in the shared DTO class):

```
/** Current Method **/

try {

    client.Get(new RequestThatWillFail());

} catch(WebServiceException ex) {
    if(ex.ErrorCode == typeof(ValidationFailedException).Name)
        Console.WriteLine("Validation error");
    else if(ex.ErrorCode == typeof(UnauthorizedException).Name)
        Console.WriteLine("Not logged in");
    else if(ex.ErrorCode == typeof(ForbiddenException).Name)
        Console.WriteLine("You're not allowed to do that!");
    else
        throw; // Unexpected exception              
}
```

Ideally I was hoping that `JsonServiceClient` would contain some helper method or overridable conversion function that would allow me to translate the `WebServiceException` to my known exception type; So that I could use my `try ... catch` in a more traditional way:

```
/** Ideal Method **/

try {

    client.Get(new RequestThatWillFail());

} catch(ValidationFailedException ex) { // (WebServiceException is converted)
    Console.WriteLine("Validation error");
} catch(UnauthorizedException ex) {
    Console.WriteLine("Not logged in");
} catch(ForbiddenException ex) {
    Console.WriteLine("You're not allowed to do that!");
}
```

**Update (for clarification)**

- I have exceptions working, I can debug, and get all the information I need to.
- But I would like to ultimately be able to catch my own exception instead of the generic WebServiceException
- I am not looking to extend additional properties on the exception, it's ultimately a convenience of not having to do lots of `typeof(MyException).Name == ex.ErrorCode` within the catch.

I would envisage being able to provide `JsonServiceClient` with a map of:

```
{ Type typeof(Exception), string ErrorCode }
```

i.e. Something like

```
JsonServiceClient.MapExceptionToErrorCode = {
    { typeof(BadRequestException), "BadRequestException" },
    { typeof(ValidationFailedException), "ValidationFailedException" },
    { typeof(UnauthorizedException), "UnauthorizedException" },
    { typeof(AnotherException), "AnotherException" }
    // ...
}
```

Similar to how the server currently maps exceptions to Http status codes.

Then the `ThrowWebServiceException<TResponse>` and the `HandleResponseError<TResponse>` within the `JsonServiceClient` could look the `ErrorCode` up in the map and if it matches, return a new Exception of that type, passing the `WebServiceException` as a parameter, or alternatively Translate the properties.

But with the ultimate goal of throwing a more useable error. If there wasn't a match, go ahead and continue throwing the `WebServiceException`.

I'd override `ThrowWebServiceException<TResponse>` and the `HandleResponseError<TResponse>` but I don't think this is possible. And I don't wan't to build my own version to provide this functionality.

I hope I have explained this OK.

Comment: if you wrap the service call in client, handle the WebServiceException as in my answer, check  the ResponseStatus errors and rethrow your exception, is it a  workaround ?

Comment: @stefan2410 So effectively write a wrapper around `JsonServiceClient` that hides catches the WebServiceException and re-throw it as my type? I see what you are saying, it might be an approach - though I worry that with the wrapper then it tied to the ServiceClient, any changes could be breaking. It may be time to conceit defeat. ServiceStack v4 is coming out, as it will be commercial, it's maybe something I can suggest. I was just looking for something to make my code neater, it's not vital, after all it is working.

Answer (score 3):

My approach for exception handling  is  to do in service side what is described in the [Structured Error Handling](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/New-Api#structured-error-handling)  and   [Overriding the default Exception handling](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/New-Api#overriding-the-default-exception-handling)
I use  my ServiceRunner and I override the  HandleException.
If my API exception is thrown then I create a custom response.

```
       public override object HandleException(IRequestContext requestContext,T request, 
                                                   Exception ex)
    {
         APIException apiex = ex as APIException;    // custo application exception
        if (apiex != null)
        {
            ResponseStatus rs = new ResponseStatus("APIException", apiex.message);
            rs.Errors = new List<ResponseError>();
            rs.Errors.Add(new ResponseError());
            rs.Errors[0].ErrorCode = apiex.errorCode.ToString();               
            rs.Errors[0].FieldName = requestContext.PathInfo;

             rs.Errors[1].ErrorCode = apiex.detailCode.ToString(); 
            // create an ErrorResponse with the ResponseStatus as parameter
            var errorResponse = DtoUtils.CreateErrorResponse(request, ex, rs);

            Log.Error("your_message", ex);   // log only the the error
            return errorResponse;

        }
        else
            return base.HandleException(requestContext, request, ex);

    }
```

UPDATE : 
**In client side, I create an wrapper for the service call and in WebServiceException,
I check the ResponseStatus.Errors**. In case of my error code,  then I rethrow my exception.

```
   T ServiceCall<T>(string command, string rest_uri, object request)
    {
        try
        {   
                if (command == "POST")
                      return client.Post<T>(serverIP+rest_uri, request);

        }
        catch (WebServiceException err)
        {
           if (err.ErrorCode == "APIException" && err.ResponseStatus.Errors != null 
                          &&  err.ResponseStatus.Errors.Count > 0)
            {
                string  error_code = err.ResponseStatus.Errors[0].ErrorCode;
                string  path_info = err.ResponseStatus.Errors[0].FieldName;  
                string detail_error = err.ResponseStatus.Errors[1].ErrorCode; 

                 throw new  APIException(error_code,detail_error,path_info);           
            } 
        } finally {}
   }
```

Comment: Thanks. I maybe need to clarify better, I am not having a problem, using exceptions. My current method is essentially the same as yours. The problem is it would be nice if the service consumer could get back their real exception from `JsonServiceClient`. It would be nice if I could map `ErrorCode` to a compatible exception of my custom type, the same as thrown on the server, shared through common dll. But it looks like `ThrowWebServiceException<TResponse>` in the `JsonServiceClient` can't be overriden. I was really looking for solutions that avoided having to branch `ErrorCode` in my `try`.